Порядок работы cin
Как пошагово работает объект cin, в подробностях.
То есть:

Ввод в консоль
Сохранение в буфер
И т.д.

Есть ли последующие или промежуточные звенья?

Не более того, что описано в стандарте о входных потоках вообще и cin в частности . Все остальное — детали реализации...

@Harry, вот насчет деталей реализации. У gpt спросил, он говорит, что при вводе в cin перед нажатием enter данные хранятся в буфере ввода, а после нажатия переходят в программу. Когда программа завершается - буфер очищается.  Правда ли это? Интересен именно буфер ввода

@Harry, можно ли сказать, что один cin - один буфер ввода? Или несколько cin используют один буфер?

cin — он единственный и неповторимый :) Нет "нескольких cin.

@Harry, а буферов ввода сколько?

Вообще-то, cin должен использовать stdin с его буфером (по крайней мере до вызова sync_with_stdio(false)), а наличием и размером буфера stdio управляет функция setvbuf

Отвечая на вопрос в комментариях.
Ну, наверное, я все же допускаю предельно странную реализацию с несколькими физическими буферами (потому и написал — детали реализации), но куда проще и логичнее иметь дело с одним. Тем более что логически он один и есть.
Согласно стандарту, istream (все basic_ опущены для краткости) использует streambuf, каковой и есть единственный логический буфер потока, и работает через этот буфер (еще раз — логически единственный, а что там на низком уровне начудить можно — дело второе. Но если про него почитать, то становится очевидно, что использовать несколько физических буферов хоть и можно, но геморрой при этом получится знатный. Так что готов спорить, что реализаций с множественными буферами просто не найти.)
Более того, используя setbuf(), вы можете использовать собственный буфер. Что как бы подчеркивает, что он один в любом случае — не представляю, зачем делать несколько буферов при работе с внутренней реализацией буфера, но один с внешней. Логично всегда иметь один буфер, код будет проще. Да и реализация всех функций для перемещения указателей по буферу в этом случае проще.
Так что несмотря на то, что стандарт об этом прямо не говорит, физический буфер потока все же единственный.
P.S. Знатоки стандарта, нет ли в стандарте прямого указания, что физический буфер единственный? А то я оставляю лазейку для особо извращенных :), но не уверен, что не зря это делаю...

cin с одной переменной
Сначала происходить ввод в консоль, пока пользователь не нажмёт enter. Во время ввода данные хранятся в буфере¹.
Если мы поставим пробел начнётся новый буфер ввода, но он не будет сохранён в переменную, а будет просто очищен.
По окончанию ввода данные из буфера записываются в переменную. Затем буфер очищается.
cin с несколькими переменными
Сначала происходит ввод в консоль если мы ставим пробел, то начинается новый буфер. В это время данные хранятся в буферах. Ввод заканчивается, когда пользователь нажмёт enter.
По окончанию ввода данные из соответствующих буферов переписываются в соответствующие переменные. Затем буфера очищаются.

1 - здесь и дальше под словом буфер подразумевается буфер ввода.

Ой что-то странное вы написали... О множественных буферах ввода, по одному на слово, про очистку... Откуда сведения?

Разве буфер после окончания ввода очищается? В комментариях тяжело писать код, так что вот так: string a; cin >> a; string b; getline(cin, b); cout << a << endl; cout << b << endl; В данном коде если ввести одно слово в консоль, то переменная b будет пуста, если несколько слов ввести, то в первую переменную поместится первое слово, а во вторую переменную поместится остальное, включая пробел в начале. Это показывает, что буфер не очищается после ввода. Очищается после окончания программы, либо после cin.ignore

@Harry, детали реализации от-туда, что я пишу свой компилятор С++.

Да сколько угодно, только не надо выдавать свою работу за всеобщий стандарт. Более того, ваши "Если мы поставим пробел начнётся новый буфер ввода, но он не будет сохранён в переменную, а будет просто очищен." со стандартом не стыкуются...
